Does Active Directory Store the last user logon information?
More specifically - does Active Directory store this information in a place other than a computer? I have a lost computer in a domain environment and I am not a AD admin but do have admin+ rights on all the computers. SCCM has this information but it is not always current. I have also checked the computer name in the Active Directory Administrative Center and there is not login information that could see. I have viewed the PowerShell output from the command:
Get-ADComputer -Identity "ComputerName" -Properties * \Some information was removed or changed.                     
                                                        Is it the lastLogon field?\

AccountExpirationDate                :
accountExpires                       : 9223372036854775807
AccountLockoutTime                   :
AccountNotDelegated                  : False
AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption    : False
AuthenticationPolicy                 : {}
AuthenticationPolicySilo             : {}
BadLogonCount                        : 0
badPasswordTime                      : 0
badPwdCount                          : 0
CannotChangePassword                 : False
CanonicalName                        : 
Certificates                         : {}
CN                                   : ComputerName
codePage                             : 0
CompoundIdentitySupported            : {False}
countryCode                          : 0
Created                              : 4/29/2019 1:16:25 PM
createTimeStamp                      : 4/29/2019 1:16:25 PM
Deleted                              :
Description                          : Refresh 5/1/19
DisplayName                          :
DistinguishedName                    :
DNSHostName                          :
DoesNotRequirePreAuth                : False
dSCorePropagationData                : {4/9/2024 10:14:37 AM, 2/22/2024 6:24:42 PM, 5/31/2023 8:05:06 PM, 3/28/2023
                                       9:31:20 AM...}
Enabled                              : True
HomedirRequired                      : False
HomePage                             :
instanceType                         : 4
IPv4Address                          :
IPv6Address                          :
isCriticalSystemObject               : False
isDeleted                            :
KerberosEncryptionType               : {RC4, AES128, AES256}
LastBadPasswordAttempt               :
LastKnownParent                      :
lastLogoff                           : 0
lastLogon                            : 133541980705291112
LastLogonDate                        : 2/29/2024 4:26:29 AM
lastLogonTimestamp                   : 133536831896176074
localPolicyFlags                     : 0
Location                             :
LockedOut                            : False
logonCount                           : 7217
ManagedBy                            :
MemberOf                             :                                                         MNSLogonAccount                      : False
Modified                             : 3/5/2024 9:06:40 AM
modifyTimeStamp                      : 3/5/2024 9:06:40 AM
msDS-KeyCredentialLink               : COSD12549
nTSecurityDescriptor                 : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity
ObjectCategory                       : 
ObjectClass                          : computername
ObjectGUID                           : 74a97a55-3909-4597-bdc3-d944a1589f6b
objectSid                            : S-1-5-21-1220945662-1606980848-1801674531-289388
OperatingSystem                      : Windows 11 Enterprise
OperatingSystemHotfix                :
OperatingSystemServicePack           :
OperatingSystemVersion               : 10.0 (22621)
PasswordExpired                      : False
PasswordLastSet                      : 3/4/2024 9:54:58 PM
PasswordNeverExpires                 : False
PasswordNotRequired                  : True
PrimaryGroup                         : 
primaryGroupID                       : 515
PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount : {}
ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion      : False
pwdLastSet                           : 133540916989401567
SamAccountName                       : 
sDRightsEffective                    : 7
ServiceAccount                       : {}
servicePrincipalName                 :                                  
SID                                  : S-1-5-21-1220945662-1606980848-1801674531-289388
SIDHistory                           : {}
TrustedForDelegation                 : False
TrustedToAuthForDelegation           : False
UseDESKeyOnly                        : False
userAccountControl                   : 4128
userCertificate                      : {}
UserPrincipalName                    :
uSNChanged                           : 823581575
uSNCreated                           : 824670
whenChanged                          : 3/5/2024 9:06:40 AM
whenCreated                          : 4/29/2019 1:16:25 PM

If it is the "lastLogon" field how do I convert to letters? I am able to extract a username from SCCM but it's not always the freshest. SCCM might be the only source but I wanted to find out if active directory might have updated info.
 Get-ADComputer -Identity "COSD12549" -Properties # this is the PowerShell command I used


The lastLogon and lastLogonTimestamp attributes can be decoded with DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc: [datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc( 133541980705291112 ). You'll want to check the lastLogon attribute value on every single Domain Controller in the domain, as this attribute is not replicated. Whichever DC has the highest value is the one that's seen the computer most recently => go look at the audit logs on that DC.

You can convert the LastLogon and LastLogonTimeStamp values as follows:
"w32tm.exe /ntte [time in Windows NT time format]
"Example:
The command w32tm.exe /ntte 128271382742968750 will yield "148462 05:57:54.2968750 - 6/24/2007 8:57:54 AM (local time)" on a computer that is in a time zone three hours ahead of Greenwich Mean Time (GMT +3:00). Notice that the first half of the output displays the time in GMT (05:57:54) and then converts" it by adding the Time Zone Offset (8:57:54)"
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/convert-datetime-attributes-to-standard-format
"LastLogon attribute is updated only on the DC that validates the logon request. The lastLogon attribute is not replicated.
In contrast the lastLogontimeStamp attribute is replicated so all DC's have the same value for the attribute (after replication convergence).
It is important to note that the intended purpose of the lastLogontimeStamp attribute to help identify inactive computer and user accounts. The lastLogon attribute is not designed to provide real time logon information. With default settings in place the lastLogontimeStamp will be 9-14 days behind the current date."
Ref: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/8220-the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-8221-8211-8220-what-it-was/ba-p/396204
Taking into account this information, LastLogon attribute will provide a more realistic value but all DCs should be queried.
If you get the computer last logon time, this is when the domain member computer was last started and contacted a DC - independent of a domain user interactive logon.
If you get the domain user last logon time, this is when the domain user logged on to the domain.

Thank you for your responses. What I am trying to determine is "WHO" logged in to a give computer last. Not what time the logon occurred. And more particularly the last user to login to a given computer. It appears from the comments that "last logon" is another time stamp? For example let's say my AD username is "KennyAD" when I log into a domain connected computer that information is stored somewhere in AD and I want to retrieve that.

Thanks for clarification. I am afraid such an information does not exist in Active Directory, a computer object does not keep the last user that logged into that workstation. What we can do for your requirement is either deploying a logon script that writes the user's computer object to a shared directory or search for the event logs for a specific ID (4672) on domain controllers that domain logon occured on the 'Given Computer Name' and find the user from event contents. In the second option the newest 4672 events that occured on the computer should be chosen.

If you have an event log collection / backup system, you can search DC event logs backwards for a specific case. The first option logon script sets up a process from now on so historical search is not possible.  LastLogon attribute is non-replicated means that only the DC which has authenticated the user is updated by LastLogon attribute. LastLogonTimeStamp is a replicated attribute to facilitate reporting, but this field may not show the exact time, may lag several days up to 14 due to DC performance reasons. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lastlogontimestamp
